# how to make flash in iframe appear under my popup window

Tags: javascript, html, flash

if i would place flash in a usual way, i could use wmode transparent.

but I place flash on page with iframe (because it loads external files, with relative URLs, from another server)

Also on a page I have JS popup window. But when opened, it's under flash in iframe. I need above.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure?

I just tried this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.websitewithflash.com/" border="0" height="300"></iframe>

<div style="width:50px;height:50px;background:red;position:absolute;top:150px;left:100px;z-index:2">
this is a test!
</div>
```

And the red "popup" appeared over the iframe and Flash (Firefox and IE)

The flash in the iframe has wmode set to transparent.

Comment: <iframe src="http://s0.2mdn.net/1914178/advancedpurchase_300x250.swf" border="0" height="300"></iframe>

<div style="width:50px;height:50px;background:red;position:absolute;top:150px;left:100px;z-index:2">
this is a test!
</div>

Comment: You can't link to the swf. You have to place it on a page with object/embed tags. Or use JavaScript: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/